# How to reuse parent page fields in child in Django Wagtail?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to reuse some fields in Django Wagtail.

I have main, root page `HomePage` as follows:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    # Footer section #
    footer_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default='My company address')
    footer_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default='My company phone')
    footer_email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default='My company email')
    footer_website = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default='My company website')
    # End Footer section #

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['logo'] = self.logo
        context['address'] = self.footer_address
        context['phone'] = self.footer_phone
        context['email'] = self.footer_email
        context['website'] = self.footer_website
        return context

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldRowPanel([FieldPanel('footer_address', classname="col3 footer_address"), FieldPanel('footer_phone', classname="col3 footer_phone"),
                       FieldPanel('footer_email', classname="col3 footer_email"), FieldPanel('footer_website', classname="col3 footer_website")], heading="Footer contact info",
                      classname="full g-py-30 footer"),
    ]
```

And there can I add in admin panel address, phone, email and website. That is fine.

But I want to be able to edit those fields in a subpage (`Vehicles`) of the `HomePage`.

In `get_context` I get the `HomePage` as `HomePage.objects.parent_of(self).live().first()` and I can pass the values of those fields in template of the subpage but how can I edit or add their values in parent from child page?

The code is as follows:

```
class Vehicles(Page):
    vehicles_list_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default=_('Discover vehicles that suit you'), verbose_name=_("Title"))

    def get_context(self, request):
        # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
        context = super().get_context(request)
        homepage_parent = HomePage.objects.parent_of(self).live().first()
        context['logo'] = homepage_parent.logo
        context['address'] = homepage_parent.footer_address
        context['phone'] = homepage_parent.footer_phone
        context['email'] = homepage_parent.footer_email
        context['website'] = homepage_parent.footer_website
        return context

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        #### What I need to do here to show and to be able to edit fields from parent page

    ]
```

Any idea?

Comment: What's the use-case? Why wouldn't you just edit the home page? Usually creating snippets and a `SnippetChooserPanel` on your pages is the best way to share blocks of fields across different pages.

Comment: Having the same piece of information editable as part of multiple pages would be a very bad idea. What happens if you change that data from the Vehicles page and save as draft - does the information get updated on Homepage or not?